# gRPC отключить вывод информации в консоль

Tags: .net, grpc, .net-5

Как выключить вывод информации (пример см. ниже) в консоль на сервере gRPC? Желательно в коде, а не в json-файле. Заранее спасибо.

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: [url]https://[::]:5001[/url]
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Content root path: C:\gRPC-Example\bin\Debug\net5.0
```

Comment: Это [логирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Нужно его отключить. Как именно - зависит от того, как оно включено. Правильнее это делать как раз с помощью файла настроек, чтобы не перекомпилировать код. И лучше не отключать полностью, а повысить уровень выше Information. | В коде смотрите `ConfigureLogging` и `LoggerFactory`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне все же надо отключить полностью и все-таки в коде. Я пробовал по методу, который в том числе и Вы дали, но у меня ругается на то, что AddFilter не определен.

Comment: Повторяю ещё раз: как именно отключить - зависит от того, как логирование включено. Никто не видит ваш код! / `LogLevel.None` поставьте.

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо.